# Is this an ok method of combining MD5 hashes?

Tags: c#, md5

I've got a tree of data and if a node changes I need to have that changes reflected in the node's hash and its parents' hashes. Whilst this method might not be suitable for military grade cryptography is it suitable for this simple task? I dont know that much about how MD5 works internally and I'm not sure if turning it in to a 32 bit integer would weaken it too much.

```
    [DataMember(Name = "hash")]
    public string Hash
    {
        get
        {
            // We convert this to a base64 string because it goes over the wire as text not an int and base64 takes up less space than 0-9
            return Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(GetRecursiveHashCode())).Trim("=".ToCharArray());
        }
        set { } // We need a setter or the property doesn't appear in the JSON
    }

    private MD5 _md5 = null;
    private int _recursiveHashCode;
    private int GetRecursiveHashCode()
    {
        return GetRecursiveHashCode(_md5 ?? MD5.Create());
    }

    private int GetRecursiveHashCode(MD5 md5)
    {
        if (_md5 == null)
            _md5 = md5;
        unchecked
        {
            if (_recursiveHashCode == 0)
            {
                _recursiveHashCode = this.GetHash(md5);
                if (Children != null)
                {
                    foreach (var child in Children)
                    {
                        _recursiveHashCode = _recursiveHashCode * 31 + child.GetRecursiveHashCode(md5);
                    }
                }
            }
            return _recursiveHashCode;
        }
    }

    public int GetHash(MD5 md5)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            string text = (ContextMenu ?? string.Empty) + "~" + HasChildren + "~" + Id + "~" + IsFolder + "~" + IsSystemFolder + "~" + Ordinal + "~" + HasChildren + "~" + SmallIcon + "~" + Title + "~" + Tooltip;
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)), 0);
        }
    }
```

I was also wondering if MD5.Create is quite resource intensive? You will notice that in the code above I'm just creating one instance of MD5 and passing it around. I could probably use something like CRC32 in place of MD5 here, would that be a faster/better solution? I get the feeling that by using MD5 I'm using a sledge hammer to crack a wallnut as the saying goes.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Actually, MD5 isn't a state of the art cryptographic hash. It's completely broken for some use cases (including preventing too many collisions in a hash table), and even for other use cases it's discouraged. However, you probably don't need any kind of collision resistance against malicious inputs, and hence no cryptographic hash function.

Comment: So something like CRC32 would be better?

Comment: From what I've seen SHA1 is slower than MD5 and this tree can have upwards of 50,000 nodes in it so speed is importnat

Comment: Why do you even consider SHA1? Do you have any reason to look at cryptographic hash functions? Are you expecting malicous trees aiming to create hash collisions? Oh and since I've only just seen it: Yes, turning *any* 128 bit hash into a 32 bit integer will significantly weaken it, it makes collisions more likely by a factor of around 2^96 (assuming the hash is decent). The hash functions for cryptographic use and those for hash tables are *very* different in almost any regard. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: What algorithm would you recommend then?

Comment: The most common scheme is hashing the members (`HasChildren`, `Title`, etc.) and combinding them into one using some arithmetic. *What* arithmetic is best is a hard question and depends on your data and the hash table implementation. A simple scheme is XOR-ing or adding them. If most of your members are booleans, you might want to concatenate those first (e.g. `HasChildren = true, IsFolder = false, ... => 0b10...`) to improve entropy. You might want to have a look at what other .NET classes (BCL or third party) composed of several hashable things do.

Comment: I had previously tried to avoid using .NET's GetHashCode method because it doesn't guarantee that you will get the same hash for the same object after something like a reboot (depending on how the developer of the class has implemented it.) However I've done some decompiling and for primitive types it looks fine. Int returns itself, bool returns 1 or 0 and string returns the XORed total of all the characters.

Comment: If you do need portability across runs, you probably also need portability across versions and platforms, and GetHashCode is unsuitable for that as it may vary between versions and platforms. But you can just implement the same algorithms yourself.